# How to solve “Query failed” error in drush sql-sync output 2?

Tags: 8, database, drush

I have the exact same problem as in [How to solve "Query failed" error in drush sql-sync output?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193296/), exact same output. That user found the answer as the password in settings.php was wrong, but my password is correct and it still doesn't work. Can anyone please help?

```
drush sql-query --strict=0 --file=/tmp/mob_20191203_224013.sql.gz --file-delete --uri=mob --root=/home/fc/1/de/mob/web -vvv
 [preflight] Config paths: /home/fc/1/de/mob/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml,/home/fc/1/de/mob/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /home/fc/1/de/mob/web/drush/sites,/home/fc/1/de/mob/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /home/fc/1/de/mob/vendor/drush/drush/src,/home/fc/1/de/mob/drush
 [bootstrap] Starting bootstrap to max [0.04 sec, 8.57 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.04 sec, 8.57 MB]
 [bootstrap] Change working directory to /home/fc/1/de/mob/web [0.04 sec, 8.57 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal 8.7.10 root directory at /home/fc/1/de/mob/web [0.04 sec, 8.76 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.04 sec, 9.06 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site mob at sites/default [0.04 sec, 9.29 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.04 sec, 9.29 MB]
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.04 sec, 9.45 MB]
 [info] Executing: command -v mysql [0.05 sec, 9.91 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_IsKDek --database=mob --host=localhost --silent -A < /tmp/mob_20191203_224013.sql.gz [0.05 sec, 9.96 MB]

In SqlCommands.php line 199:

  [Exception]    
  Query failed.
```

/tmp/mob_20191203_224013.sql.gz exists, /tmp/drush_IsKDek does not
Drush is 9.7.1, Mint 19.2, alias

```
loc:
  root: /home/fc/1/de/mob/web
  uri: mob
  options:
    command-specific:
      sql-sync:
        sanitize: true
        structure-tables:
          common:
            - cache_advagg
            - cache_bootstrap
            - cache_config
            - cache_container
            - cache_data
            - cache_default
            - cache_discovery
            - cache_dynamic_page_cache
            - cache_entity
            - cache_menu
            - cache_page
            - cache_render
            - cache_toolbar
            - watchdog
            - history
            - sessions
    os: Linux
  paths:
    dump-dir: /tmp
    files: sites/default/files
```

Comment: Have you had a look at SqlCommands.php line 199?

Comment: Yes. Nothing useful.
`$result = $sql->query($query, $filename, $options['result-file']);`
$query is empty, filename is the .gz archive, resultfile empty, $result empty.

Comment: Probably better to report this one at GitHub. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues

Comment: It looks like the problem is at `Executing: mysql ... < /tmp/asdf.sql.gz` I don't think mysql can unzip gz transparently. Removing the `--silent` flag and running that line directly would help with debugging, but I'm not sure how to convince drush to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Drush 10.6.x. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4319#issuecomment-649223069 is outdated as the function has been moved elsewhere but the problem persists.

Solution is to manually set PHP CLI to a lower version, for example

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this comment, there is a problem in drush 9 with php7.4 as mentioned here: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4319#issuecomment-649223069

I solved it in my case (I have multiple PHP versions installed) by switching to php7.2 using this command:
`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2`

I think it will work also with php7.0 and php7.1